# Persistent Terminal Output

Tags: python

Consider something like lynx or nano/pico/vi - is there any way to get a persistent output in the terminal window with Python? Specifically, I'm looking for something like `output(char, x, y)` which will replace the current character at (x, y) in the terminal with char, rather like the old TI-8(3|4)s.

Answer (score 4):

[`curses`](http://docs.python.org/library/curses.html)

Answer (score 0):

another way would be http://www.termsys.demon.co.uk/vtansi.htm#cursor

```
>>> ESC = chr(0x1b)
>>> print ESC + '[5;5ftest',
```

works on most xterms, which tend to be vt100-compliant.